# How can remove part of a string using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'd like to remove the time portions from these strings:

Original strings:

- ABC: Playground Game 11:30 am - 12:20 pm
- DEF: Inside Game 12:30 pm -    2:00 pm

Desired strings:

- ABC: Playground Game
- DEF: Inside Game

How can I do this using regular expressions?

Comment: Could do it with some trim  `^\s*(?!\s)(\D+)(?<!\s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`^\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/niN9LM/1)

Flags: Global, Multiline.

Captures all non-digit characters from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it's not quite this simple for me but this led me to solving my problem. What I needed was the "\D+" and with it, I was able to complete my task.